# Send sound to AV receiver but have only 1 monitor in Windows

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, av-receiver

I have a very complicated problem that I hope you can help me with.

I have the following setup:

- PC with:

  - DVI out to primary monitor
  - HDMI out to AV-receiver, which then goes to TV and 5.1 sound system

I want my sound to play on the AV-receiver. To do this, I have to "Extend" or "Duplicate" my desktop to the AV-receiver (i.e. the TV). If I do not do this, the sound also doesn't go to the AV-receiver.
However:

- Extending desktop is a problem, because my TV is not always on, and windows will still randomly move to this 2nd monitor (I can get them back with `Windows` + `Shift` + `L_ARROW` but this is not ideal...)
- Duplicating desktop is a problem, because my TV is 16:9 and my PC monitor is 21:9

So what I need is a solution that allows me to still send the sound through HDMI to my AV-receiver, but have only 1 desktop on my monitor (not on my TV). Obviously, the option to extend to my TV should still be available, should I want to watch a movie on my TV.

I hope my question is clear, and I hope someone knows a solution. I don't mind a solution that uses 3rd party software.

Comment: When the tv is plugged in, and you right click on the volume icon in the tray for playback devices, try right clicking and setting it (tv or av device, whichever shows) to default device. When the monitor is disabled from your PC, the setting should stay and work.

Comment: Hi Narzard, thanks for your suggestion. As soon as I set my Display Setting to "Display 1 Only" (my monitor) - in stead of "Extend" or "Duplicate" - the AV-receiver disappears from the Playback Devices list. Even if I set it as Default Device, it still disappears as soon as I disable the 2nd screen. 

My problem is not that my TV has to be on. The TV can be off, that's not a problem. The problem is that my PC is constantly rendering a second screen (1920x1080 if I don't change it), which kinda hurts my FPS when playing games for example, even though the TV is turned off.

Comment: Please refer to: http://superuser.com/questions/483720/how-to-use-hdmi-display-device-audio-output-without-extending-the-desktop-to-tha . First answer states: It seems that the GPU is responsible for the signal that is sent to display, therefore it does not seem possible to only get audio from a GPU's output. Any other suggestions, anyone?